# Read Error Message with HttpURLConnection send by Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, httpurlconnection

I have a Spring-MVC controller using Json request parameters. If the validation of this parameter fails, I want to send a custom error message.

Therefore, I added this ExceptionHandler to my controller which seams to work (breakpoint is reached during debugging).

**Controller Class:**

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
     return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Custom Message");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/doMagic", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getAllStudies(@Validated @RequestBody JsonDTO params)
{
    ...
}
```

On the client site I use the HttpURLConnection from Java utils.

**Client Class:**

```
private static String getErrorString(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException{
    if(connection.getErrorStream() != null) {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        return response.toString();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is, the error message is always

`Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: www.test.de/doMagic`

How do I receive my `Custom Message`?

**Edit:**

If I change the return status of the ExceptionHandler to `HttpStatus.OK`, the `Custom Message`is send successfully and can be read by the client. So, the problem seams to be a Spring Bean (?) or the HttpConnection replacing the body in case of an error status.

Comment: where you call handleException() ?

Comment: It's done automatically by Spring, if `@Validated` fails.

Comment: What is the URL and access method in `HttpURLConnection connection` ?

Comment: URL is `www.test.de/doMagic` and access method is of course `Post` since the validation is successfully triggered.

Comment: Please post your JsonDTO

Comment: The JsonDTO is not the problem, see my edit.

Comment: Is there any reason that you prefer HttpURLConnection. If you are using spring on client side as well, then you can use Spring's RestTemplate and configure an error handler to handle failed requests and read the response body.

Comment: Client site is "plain" Java without Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object specifically for returning error responses. That way, you can say whatever you want.
Like: `ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus>`